# File name solves issue, why?

Tags: jquery, html, window, width, filenames

I had been struggling with an issue for a while.  I had created a website and when I switched from one page to any of the other pages, my header width was different.  I figured out that for that one page it interpreted the window width to be different (jquery window.width()).  Specifically for that page, it returned a larger window.width value than for all of the other pages (where the width of the window was rightly reported for the other pages but not for this one page).  I then, as a last resort, decided to copy and paste the same code in a new file and load this file.  Funnily enough, the same code, now saved under a different file name, interpreted the window width correctly and thus fixed the problem.  When I then saved this file under my original file name, the problem re-occurred, i.e. the window.width() was larger than the actual width of the window.

Sorry I have no re-create-able example, but I have no idea how this error occured.  Or, how it is solved by changing the file name.  I believe this means that the file name had a specific impact on the document, and that I must have told my computer to interpret this file name that way, but I am really lost here.

Anyone have any idea what might have happened here?

Comment: I'd check for rewrite rules on the server.

Comment: Different filename extension (server sending different mime type, or prepend/appending based on document type)? Server side scripts (PHP, ASP, ASP.NET, etc) doing something conditional on the document name?  Client side script checking window.location? Copy and paste error (Forget the doctype)? Are you placing the name of the document on the page?

Comment: Barmar, there was no server to connect to, I checked all of this on my computer and just loaded the documents in chrome, I already discovered these differences and worked on them before making the website go live.  Unless I am misinterpreting server. Sorry this wasn't clear.  Robert,  I think your first 3 questions are answered based on the answer to Barmar.  No, doctype was always there and I do not place the name of the document on the page.

Comment: so html files with different names but same code result in different outputs? interesting. my first guess would be that your original file was somehow corrupted. Or new-file had different encodings so same code was interpreted differently.
Can you tell us those files names and their encodings?

Comment: Hi Raj, sorry for delay, had to run.  Exactly.  I changed the file name between bla.html to home_prof.html to index.html.  Bla and index gave no issues however home_prof.html (my original file name) gave repeated issues.  What do you mean with encodings exactly?  Also, I don't think it was that file, because I made a new file where it worked (under bla.html) but I changed this file to home_prof.html, and then it didn't work again.  It seems directly related to the file name.